# How to get the DirectX::Image (from DirectXTex) structure based on ID3D11Texture2D?

Tags: c++, directx, directx-11, texture2d, render-to-texture

I have an custom texture class:

```
class Texture{
    ID3D11Texture2D * renderTargetTexture;
public:
    ...
    void saveToTGA(std::wstring filePath);
};
```

I am using this texture as render target between render passes. I want to write the `saveToTGA(std::wstring filePath)` method which saves the texture to file (kind of a screenshot).

[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476298%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) says that `D3DX11SaveTextureToFile(...)` is depreciated so I decided to use DirectXTex library as they suggested.

I know I have to use:

```
DirectX::Image image = ...
DirectX::SaveToTGAFile(image, filePath.c_str());
```

But the problem is: how to get the `DirectX::Image` (from DirectXTex) structure based on `ID3D11Texture2D` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From MSDN document you could use

> Blockquote we recommend that you use the DirectXTex library, CaptureTexture then SaveToXXXFile (where XXX is WIC, DDS, or TGA; WIC doesn't support DDS and TGA; D3DX 9 supported TGA as a common art source format for games).

So, first you capture your texture from the texture buffer using

```
HRESULT hr = DirectX::CaptureTexture(m_D3D->GetDevice(), m_D3D->GetDeviceContext(), resourceContext, image);
```

and follow with Save function

```
hr = DirectX::SaveToDDSFile(image.GetImages(),image.GetImageCount(), image.GetMetadata(), DirectX::DDS_FLAGS_NONE, Filename);
```

Please see this reference https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTex/wiki/CaptureTexture